# Passing array from Flask to Javascript to create options for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, flask

I am new to Flask and Javascript. I am trying to upload a file and use one of its columns as options in the drop down menu. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Here are the codes:

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['csv'])

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['data_file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            names = data['some_column']
            return redirect(url_for('drop_down', names=names))
            #return render_template('drop_down.html', names=names)
    return render_template('file_upload.html')

@app.route('/meta')
def drop_down():
    return render_template('drop_down.html')
```

Javascript:

```
function my_script(){
    console.log('script called.');
    //var cars = ["Volvo","Ferrari","Audi","BMW","Mercedes","Porche","Saab","Avanti"];
    var cars = {{ names|safe }};
    console.log('cars assigned.');

    function make_drop_down(list_of_names, element_id){
        select_elem = document.getElementById(element_id)
        if(select_elem){
            for(var i = 0; i < list_of_names.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.innerHTML = list_of_names[i];
                option.value = list_of_names[i];
                select_elem.appendChild(option);
            }
        }       
    };

    console.log("Making Drop Downs!!");
    make_drop_down(cars, 'drop_down_1');
    make_drop_down(cars, 'drop_down_2');
    console.log("Made Drop Downs!!");

};
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/drop_down.js"></script>
    <title>DROP DOWN</title>    
</head>
    <body onload="my_script()">
        <select id="drop_down_1">
            <option>Choose Option 1</option>

        </select>

        </br></br>

        <select id="drop_down_2">
            <option>Choose Option 2</option>

        </select>


    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error on the console:
ReferenceError: my_script is not defined

Comment: How are you passing the names in {{ names|safe }} to your javascript?

Comment: Have a look at: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

The first one is that you are not passing the list of cars in your view handeling `/meta`

```
@app.route('/meta')
def drop_down():
   return render_template('drop_down.html')
```

This should probably look something like this:

```
@app.route('/meta')
def drop_down():
   cars = ["Volvo","Ferrari","Audi","BMW","Mercedes","Porche","Saab","Avanti"]
   return render_template('drop_down.html',
                          names=cars)
```

The second problem is that your javascript won't be able to access the list, unless you pass it in your call to the function.

html

```
<body onload="my_script({{ names }})">
```

javascript

```
function my_script(names){
   console.log('script called.');
   var cars = names;
   ...
```

Edit:

The function that handles the view is the function that needs to pass the data. You could also use the commented away part of your upload file, which calls `render_template...` with the necessary data, but this doesn't feel as a "nice" approach.

You need to make the data available to your `drop_down()` view, either by storing it in a database, reading the data from the file in this function or by storing it in the session. So that you can pass the data along with the template

Comment: Can you please explain why cars array is required in the drop_down() function? I wanted to take the input (names) from the uploaded file.