# Sending an Array from Python to JS

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

I am new to python and JS. I am trying to call a python method from a js code. The python code is supposed to do some calculation and returns me the results which is array of arrays (e.g., [[1,3],[3, 5]]). I have looked at few answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458354/passing-array-from-flask-to-javascript-to-create-options-for-drop-down-menu). However, I was not able to solve my problem. Below is what I have so far:

JS code : This sends string "start" to my python code.

```
  var a = $.post("/mlModel", {
    Ml_list: JSON.stringify("start"),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
  });
  console.log(JSON.parse(a));
```

Python Code: Python code gets the string "start", does some process, and return the results in the form of array of arrays [[2,4],[2,6]]

```
enter code here
@app.route('/mlModel', methods = ['POST'])
def get_post_MlModel():
   jsdata = request.form['Ml_list']
   jsdata = json.loads(jsdata)
   jsdata = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(jsdata)) 

   // I send "start" to calculate method and it returns data = [[2,3],[1,3]]
   data = calculate(jsdata) 
   return json.dumps(data)
```

When I run this code, this returns me "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Any idea?

Comment: can you show us the json you are sending?

Comment: @MikeTung you mean from python to js? when print data it returns [[1 1]
 [0 1]] but when I print json.dumps(data), It does not print anything.

Comment: looks like you aren't sending valid json to the python server. When the python server tries to do `json.loads(jsdata)` you will get a error like that if the json is invalid. You can try something like `Ml_list: JSON.stringify({myKey: "start"}),`

Comment: @AndrewLohr Thanks. The python code gets the "start" correctly. The problem is when I am trying to return the value to JS. When I print data on the python side, I am getting a correct value (meaning that the python code was able to send the "start" to calculate method and return the value). does that make sense?

Comment: okay so the error comes from the client side? maybe from `console.log(JSON.parse(a));` can you print just `a` and see what that prints?

Comment: @AndrewLohr {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}     ----- It returns an object that I have no idea what is in it

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is an asynchronous operation so `a` isn't ready yet when you try to use the JSON in the response. try using a callback which is called when the request is finished

```
  $.post("/mlModel", {
    Ml_list: JSON.stringify("start"),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log("success " + JSON.parse(data));
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error( "failure " + errorThrown );
  })
```

Comment: if you open the network tab in your browser do you see the request finishing?

Comment: the color of the request is red. So I assume it is not finishing.

Comment: I added error handling for you in the answer. This can help debug more on why your request failed

Comment: Cool. main.js:166 failure INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: looks like another problem on your python server then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the typical python and javascript code used while sending and receiving objects over the server. The example below sends a string ("start") from the client and returns a list of sequential index pairs as lists.

On the python side:

```
@app.route('/testQuery', methods=['POST'])
def testQuery():
    queryString = request.form['queryString']
    outputList = []
    for i in range(0,len(queryString)):
        char = queryString[i]
        outputList.append([i,(i+1)])
    return jsonify({
        "outputList" : outputList
    })
```

On the javascript side:

```
$.post("/testQuery", {"queryString": "start"})
        .done(function (response) {
            console.log(response)                
        });
```

Hope that helps.